Is the d-n pattern in the Scythian river names (that's the evidence for the Scythian word for "river" being *danu) actually statistically significant?
So, back in 2022, I published a paper in which I apply basic information theory to calculate that the p-value of the k-r pattern in the Croatian river names (Krka, Korana, Krapina, Krbavica, Kravarščica, and two rivers named Karašica) is somewhere between 1/300 and 1/17. That paper is called "Etimologija Karašica", and you can read the English-language summary of that paper.
Recently, that calculation has led me to wonder this: If the p-value of the k-r pattern in the Croatian river names is probably somewhere slightly less than 1/17 (as, like my Information Theory professor says, not a lot of collision entropy goes to morphology, so the p-value is closer to 1/17 than 1/300), how can the d-n pattern in the Scythian river names be statistically significant? As far as I understand it, the primary evidence we have that the Scythian word for "river" was *danu is the d-n pattern in the river names where Scythian was spoken in antiquity. But, as far as I know, there are only 4 such river names: Danube, Dniester, Dnieper, and Don. Out of presumably hundreds of river names all over the places where Scythian was spoken. So, how can that pattern possibly be statistically significant?
I've asked a question on Quora about why the k-r pattern in the Croatian river names is considered spurious while the d-n pattern in the Scythian river names is considered real, and a few people told me that's because words starting with d-n are rare in Slavic languages, while words on k-r are common in Slavic languages. However, as far as I understand it, that's a misunderstanding of the information theory. The only thing that matters about the language when calculating the p-values of the patterns in toponyms is the collision entropy. There is no obvious way to modify my calculations to take into account how common the words starting in k-r are in Croatian.

If there's no way to modify your calculations to take into account the common-ness of KR as an onset, then that looks like a serious problem in your methodology! Entropy is only relevant with respect to some baseline model.

@Draconis Or maybe it really doesn't matter. Like there is no way to modify the Toricelli's Law to account for the density of the liquid. Our intuition tells us it matters, but if math tells us otherwise...

The input to the collision entropy calculation is a probability distribution. This is where the frequencies of different letters and combinations would be included. Did you assume a uniform distribution?

@Draconis Assuming uniform distribution would be claiming that a single consonant carries around log2(20) bits of entropy. I didn't do that. I measured the collision entropy of a single consonant to be log2(14) bits, and the collision entropy of the pairs of consonants to be around 5.992 bits.

I will make some points and then try to answer your question, but keep in mind that I don’t have a very sophisticated knowledge of statistical and mathematical methods for historical linguistics. Your question could be rephrased, using more down-to-earth terms, as: “Why does the sequence d-n, found in only four Eastern European hydronyms, count as sufficient evidence for the existence of the Scythian word *dānu- ‘river’, while the sequence k-r does not?”
I have been reading other similar questions you asked on StackExchange, Quora and Reddit before posting this answer just to make sure I correctly understand your point of view. To be honest, I don’t know if I have achieved that, but let me introduce a few starting points.
First of all, it is not accurate to say that “[…] the primary evidence we have that the Scythian word for "river" was *danu (sic) is the d-n pattern in the river names where Scythian was spoken in antiquity”. That Scythian had a word *dānu- (with a long *ā) meaning ‘river’ is reasonably deduced based on comparative evidence. Other Indo-Iranian languages have almost identical terms for the same concept. Most notably, the word don ‘river’ (< *dānu-) is attested in Iron and Digoron, the two major dialects of Ossetian, which is generally regarded as either the direct descendant of Scythian or as a language very close to it. Perhaps even more crucially, in the Jassic dialect, once spoken in Hungary until the 15th century, this exact same word for ‘river’ was pronounced dan (see Sárközy 2020: 101). Note that the change *ā > o before a nasal is well attested in Ossetian, but it is considered a recent development, given its absence in Medieval (i.e. Alanic and Jassic) documents (see Thordarson 1989: 460, §4.2.5.2.1.4). Younger Avestan also has dānu- ‘river’ (AirWb 733a s.v. dānav-), from which compounds like Frazdānu- or Frazdānauua- ‘name of a river’, and dānu-drājah- ‘having the length of a river’ are formed. Moreover, in Sanskrit the word dānu- means something like ‘liquid, drop’ and has the same etymon (EWA I, 719-20), which at this point can be reconstructed as *dáHnu- in Proto-Indo-Iranian. So, it’s not like we know that the Scythian word for ‘river’ is *dānu- just because it is present in the names Danube, Don, Dnieper and Dniester, but because it is suggested by the aforementioned Iranian cognates (bear in mind that we are talking about reconstructions anyway). The fact that we can also find such form in names of rivers located in the original Scythian territory is to be expected.
Second, it is not entirely sure whether Danube and its ancient equivalents, such as Latin Dānubius, Greek Δανούβιος, Δανούιος, Old High German Tuonouwa, Gothic Δούναβιν †Dōnawi- (acc.), Old Church Slavonic Доунавъ Dunavŭ, etc., are ultimately from Scythian (i.e. Iranian) or Celtic, although the name is perhaps connected with that of a river goddess (see Mallory and Adams 2006: 434). Of course, Proto-Celtic *dānu- ~ *dāno- (in *Dānowyos) and Scythian *dānu- are so similar that it is impossible to tell which one is the source of this hydronym. However, Dnieper and Dniester are rather transparent Iranian compounds. The former can be etymologized as *dān(u)-apara- ‘far river’, while the latter as *dān(u)-nazdya- ‘near river’. We are allowed to conclude (or, at least, to assume) that a sequence such as d-n in river names is diagnostic of a Scythian presence in this region because we already know that Scythian had the word *dānu- ‘river’, and most of these river names have seemingly good Iranian etymologies.
Third, I am perfectly open to the idea that the sequence k-r found in river names of Croatian is diagnostic of some Indo-European language, but if it is true, you should be able argue that such a root existed in Proto-Indo-European and fits the (supposed) meanings of the hydronyms, in line with what we have been saying until this point. If I had to guess, I would say that the best candidate to look into is probably Illyrian. The following explanation is admittedly very speculative, but the names of Krapina and Krbavica river could go back to Proto-Indo-European *kerp- ‘to pluck, shave’, which became *karp- in Illyrian. More specifically, Krapina could very likely be derived from *karp-inā, possibly meaning something like ‘rock of a river bank’. The suffix *-ino-, *-inā- is not unheard of in Illyrian onomastics (cf. Παρθῖνοι, Βουλινοί, Bulsinus, Nedinum, Rhizinium, Olcinum, Rudini, Birziminium, etc., see Katičić 1976: 173-74, 157-58, fn. 280, 286); this word could be further related to Albanian karmë ‘a rock sticking out of the river bank’ < *karpnā (Orel 1998: 171). As for Krbavica and Kravarščica, they could be connected with Albanian karpë ‘rocky hill’ < *karpā (Orel ibid.). These are good matches in light of their meaning. The two rivers named Karašica may be formed from the Illyrian base *kirši- or *kriši- ‘to hurry’. This probably comes from Proto-Indo-European *ḱr̥s-i-, the augmented zero grade of *ḱers- ‘to run’. You don’t need to suppose that Illyrian was centum in order to make this hypothesis, since Indo-European palatovelars generally depalatalized before or after sonorants in Albanian (Orel 2000: 70-71, §1.4.3.9) and possibly also in Illyrian and Liburnian. I do not have a convincing explanation for Krka and Korana rivers. Be it as it may, the “Illyrian path” seems the most promising, so I encourage you look more into that if you haven’t already.
So, why don’t linguists think that the sequence k-r is as significant as d-n? Well, it may be due to the fact that Paleo-Balkan languages, with the exception of Albanian, are poorly attested. If we cannot reconstruct any proto-form, or if the only reconstructed forms are very theoretical and based on the comparison with a single language (as in the case of Illyrian), then we cannot be sure whether the patterns we observe in Croatian hydronymy are real or are just due to pure chance. Doing calculations is not going to solve the problem, because in attempting to establish an etymology for a place name you don’t just want to know if it’s likely, but if it’s plausible. Remember that, as I’ve already said above when I’ve discussed the situation of Scythian, we start with the knowledge of the lexicon (either attested or reconstructed) of a specific language, and only then we try to match words with sequences of letters found in the toponymy. Don’t get me wrong: I am not saying that math or statistics is useless in historical linguistics, I am just saying that we need to have a good knowledge base before coming up with etymologies.
References

AirWb = Bartholomae, Christian. 1904. Altiranisches Wörterbuch. Strassburg: Verlag von Karl J. Trübner.
EWA = Mayrhofer, Manfred. 1992-2001. Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Altindoarischen. Vols. I-III. Heidelberg: Carl Winter Universitätsverlag.
Katičić, Radoslav. 1976. Ancient Languages of the Balkans. Vol. 1. The Hague: Mouton.
Mallory, James P. and Adams, Douglas Q. 2006. The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World. Oxford University Press.
Orel, Vladimir. 1998. Albanian Etymological Dictionary. Leiden & Boston: Brill.
Orel, Vladimir. 2000. A Concise Historical Grammar of the Albanian Language. Leiden & Boston: Brill.
Thordarson, Fridrik. 1989. Ossetic. In R. Schmidt (ed.), Compendium Linguarum Iranicarum, pp. 456-479. Wiesbaden: Dr. Ludvig Reichert Verlag.
Sárközy, Miklós. 2020. A magyarországi jászok nyelvemlékei – források, problémák, új adatok. Keletkutatás 89(?): 89-110.

